# Add custom image upload in tinymce

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

tinymce and using image upload, I have modified my config and added image upload from system.This is working fine and got new tab upload and below is my config :

```
config: any = {
    height: 250,
    theme: 'modern',
    // powerpaste advcode toc tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker mediaembed linkchecker help
    plugins: 'print preview searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image imagetools link media template codesample table charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
    toolbar: 'formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent fontselect fontsizeselect | removeformat',
    image_advtab: true,
    imagetools_toolbar: 'rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage imageoptions',
    menubar: true,
    statusbar: false,
    images_upload_handler: (blobInfo, success, failure) => {
      let firmuseracctid;
      let loggedInUserData = JSON.parse((sessionStorage.getItem('userDetails')));
      if (loggedInUserData && loggedInUserData.useracctid) {
        firmuseracctid = loggedInUserData.useracctid
      }
      var formData;
      formData = new FormData();
      let s3signatureKey = 'path';
      let headerImageName = blobInfo.filename();
      let status: any = 0;
      formData.append('status', status);
      formData.append('signatureKey', s3signatureKey);
      formData.append("file", blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
      //console.log(formData);
      this.uploadFile(formData).subscribe(response => {
        if (response) {
          this.headerImageUrl = 'myURL';
          success(this.headerImageUrl);
        }
      });
    },
    content_css: [
      '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
      '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    ]
  };
```

Now i need to add another tab where i have to load all images from my service side, For this how to add in config, Any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE has no configuration option to create an entire UI for browsing your repository of images.  To do this you have a few options.

TinyMCE makes two products that can do this for you:

- MoxieManager
- TinyDrive

There are 3rd party plugins that can do this for you such as:

- Responsive File Manager
- Roxy Fileman

Lastly you could choose to create your own file manager and use TinyMCE's APIs to interact with what you create (that is all the above tools do).